# Interfaces and jaxb

Tags: java, xml, interface, jaxb

i will show you my code it will be more clear:

```
@XmlRootElement
FilePollerConf{

    ArrayList<Directory> directoriesList = new ArrayList<Directory>();

}

Directory{

    ArrayList<Match> matchList = new ArrayList<Match>();

}

Match{

    ArrayList<Event> eventsList = new ArrayList<Event>();

}

Event{

    ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();

}

IAction{

    void send();

}
```

Here is the point, when i try to unmarshal with jaxb, i have the error:

> IAction is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.

So i looked for @XmlAdapter but i didn't see a use case like mine so i don't really know if i can use it ? I continue to search but if you have an idea it could be welcome ! I already have my xml in fact and i want that jaxb generate me that (give you the xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FilePollerConfiguration>
    <Directory path="C://Users//jmoreau040612//Desktop//Old">
        <Match pattern="*.xml">
       <Event name="create">
           <FTPSend>
          <FTPServer>toto.com</FTPServer>
          <FTPPort>21</FTPPort>
          <Login>toto</Login>
          <Password>titi</Password>
          <destinationPath>/root/src</destinationPath>
      </FTPSend>
       </Event>
   </Match>
        <Match pattern="*.csv">
       <Event name="modify">
           <MailSend>
          <Name>MailSend</Name>
          <SMTPServer>smtp.fr.gric</SMTPServer>
          <SMTPPort>25</SMTPPort>
          <MailTo>toto@rock.com</MailTo>
          <MailFrom>titi@rock.com</MailFrom>
          <Subject>tata</Subject>
          <Body>blabla</Body>
      </MailSend>
       </Event>
   </Match>
    </Directory>
    <Directory path="C://Users//jmoreau040612//Desktop//New">
        <Match pattern="*.csv">
       <Event name="create">
           <ServerToServer>
                    <location>ergrthrhdrth</location>
                    <destination>ergergeg</destination>
                </ServerToServer>    
       </Event>
   </Match>
   <Match pattern="*.csv">
       <Event name="delete">
           <SFTPSend>
          <SFTPServer>toto.sgcib.com</SFTPServer>
          <SFTPPort>21</SFTPPort>
          <Login>toto</Login>
          <Password>titi</Password>
          <destinationPath>/root/src</destinationPath>
          <PrivateKeyFile>C://Desktop/privatekey.prk</PrivateKeyFile>
      </SFTPSend>
       </Event>
   </Match>
    </Directory>
</FilePollerConfiguration>
```

The point is that my structure will not be always the same, so can i use jaxb ?

Comment: Try converting IAction to an abstract class (or add an abstract class that implements IAction). That's worked for me, but I don't know if will fit your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the implmenentation type for the interface field/property.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event{

    @XmlElement(type=ActionImpl.class)
    ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what i dont understand is that there will have several implementations of my interface IAction, it could be a list with four different type so i cant write @XmlElement(type=FTPSend.class) @XmlElement(type=MailSend.class)@XmlElement(type=ServerToServerSend.class) ?

Comment: @JulienMoreau - You can wrap multiple instances of `@XmlElement` in an `@XmlElements` annotation.

Comment: @XmlElements(value = { @XmlElement(type=FTPSend.class), @XmlElement(type=SFTPSend.class), @XmlElement(type=MailSend.class), @XmlElement(type=ServerToServerSend.class) }) ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();                                                                                                                                      This way looks to work ! Thanks you save me !

Comment: God just saw that you work in Ottawa, i was here last year and i dream to come back in the way to kork and live in Canada ! try to know the chance you have !

Comment: @JulienMoreau - Ottawa is definitely a nice city to live/work in.  The job market in Ottawa seems to be picking up lately.

Comment: I didnt know that Oracle was in Ottawa ! I like Ontario but i hope to immigrate in Québec in 2 years, after the end of my studies ! Are you canadian ?

Comment: @JulienMoreau - Oracle has offices all over and at least 2 in Quebec (Montreal and Quebec City).  Yes I'm Canadian, I grew up in a small town near Toronto.

Comment: Course in Montreal, I love your country ! I will come back in Ottawa for sure, maybe I could see you and talk a bit about jaxb with you !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will work, but did you try with an abstract class instead of an Interface?

I wonder JaxB requires to instanciate the class to make the transformation...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to use `@XmlAnyElement` to avoid errors on marshalling and unmarshalling of a class that contains an interface as an element. This leads to a drawback which is the type at unmarshalling time. If you use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` and specify either `@XmlRootElement` with a specific name on the concrete class or xsi:type on the element that is being unmarshalled, it will unmarshall perfectly well to your concrete class. I don't know how to do the latter but the former is quite simple to use (`@XmlRootElement(name="my-concrete-element")`).

As a matter of example:

```java
public interface Abstract {

    public void setData(String data);
    public String getData();

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "concrete1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Concrete1 implements Abstract {

    @XmlElement
    private String data;

    @Override
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "@Concrete1{data: " + this.data + "}";
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "concrete2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Concrete2 implements Abstract {

    @XmlElement
    private String data;

    @Override
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "@Concrete2{data: " + this.data + "}";
    }

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    private String prop;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "abstracts")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private ArrayList<Abstract> abstracts;

    public void setAbstracts(ArrayList<Abstract> abstracts) {
        this.abstracts = abstracts;
    }

    public ArrayList<Abstract> getAbstracts() {
        return abstracts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "{prop: " + this.prop + ", abstracts: [";
        Object[] abstracts = this.abstracts.toArray();
        for(Object abstract: abstracts) {
            ret += abstract.toString() + ", ";
        }
        return ret + "]}";
    }

    public void setProp(String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    public String getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

}
```

If someone knows how to force xsi:type to appear in the concrete classes without using any hardcoded solution, I would appreciate that share the solution.